# Saving Info from CSV to Text

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe as follows:

```
image_id  x   y    w   h   x_center  y_center img_height img_width  lable
01       500 400  250 500    309.4     543.5    2500       4000       0
01       560 430  260 570    306.7     553.4    2200       3000       0
01       540 440  270 580    387.8     563.5    2700       2000       0
02       545 340  250 590    377.8     543.5    2100       2030       1
04       546 240  240 500    367.8     553.5    2300       2000       2
04       586 270  640 400    467.8     556.5    2400       1000       2
```

I need to save these informatin for YOLO model type Text file for each `image_id`. To do that, I need to save info as

```
labels x_center y_center w h
```

Also While saving information into text file, I need to normalize the `x_center` and `w` by the image width (`img_width`) and `y_center` and `height` by the image height (`img_height`).

## My Trial

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_img_id = df.groupby('image_id')

for index, row in df_img_id:
    img_w = row['img_width']
    img_h = row['img_height']

    with open(f'{row['imgage_id']}.txt], 'w+') as f1:
        ft.write()
        f1.close()
```

Stuck at this point. :(

Comment: Looks like 'ft' is a typo, should be 'f1'? In any case the write method won't do anything unless you pass it something to write. Also, you don't need to close the file when you use 'with', it does it for you.

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve it as following. Let's create a dummy data frame first.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

info = {
    'image_id': ['01', '01', '01', '02', '04', '04'],
    'x':random.sample(range(500, 600), 6),
    'y':random.sample(range(200, 500), 6),
    'w':random.sample(range(200, 300), 6),
    'h':random.sample(range(400, 600), 6),
    'x_center':random.sample(range(250, 460), 6),
    'y_center':random.sample(range(250, 460), 6),
    'img_height':random.sample(range(2100, 3000), 6), 
    'img_width':random.sample(range(1100, 4000), 6), 
    'labels':[0,0,0,1,2,2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=info)
df.head()

--------------------------

    image_id    x    y   w  h   x_center  y_center  img_height  img_width   labels
0     01       561  435 290 449 303        318      2105        2806         0
1     01       583  447 265 427 394        421      2338        2047         0
2     01       520  417 262 592 429        395      2947        3388         0
3     02       516  415 214 470 455        319      2649        1594         1
4     04       522  386 204 514 343        394      2847        1770         2
```

Next, we will `groupyby` the **image id** and iterate over each row.

```py
df_image_id = df.groupby('image_id') # group by id

for _ , row in df_image_id:
    for _ , each in row.iterrows(): # iterate each samples within same id 
        img_w = each['img_width']  
        img_h = each['img_height']

        content = [
            each['labels'], 
            each['x_center']/each['img_width'],
            each['y_center']/each['img_height'],
            each['w']/each['img_width'],
            each['h']/each['img_height']
        ]

        id = each['image_id']
        with open(f'{id}.txt', 'a') as f1:
            f1.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in content)+ '\n')
```